# extract part of the text from all matching lines

Tags: sed, awk, string, for

I am running a for loop against set of servers to find the cert expiry. Output of the cert command will be below for each server:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
Valid From: Tuesday, 29 September 2015 10:40:13 AM To: Friday, 28 September 2018 10:40:13 AM
line 5
```

Goal is to extract only date part after To:

I was able to get this working with following command

`sed -n -e '/Valid/ s/.*\, *//p' |awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3 }')"`

But the problem is it is printing only the last occurence ignoring all the occurences of "Valid"

Here is the for loop I am running

```
for host in `cat /home/MO/server.txt`
do
for qmgr in $(ssh musr@$host dspmq)
do
certexp="$(ssh musr@$host <cert command> <path to cert> |sed -n -e '/Valid/ s/.*\, *//p' |awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3 }')"
echo "$host     :       $qmgr      :       $certexp" > out.txt
done
done
```

the output file is print only from the last server in the server.text file.

Idea was to have a file with host name, qmgr name and cert expiry date, sort it by date and then take action.

Comment: try `>> out.txt`

Comment: Aha., thank you. I had that in the backup script and forgot to make this change.

Comment: Not sure if I have to start a new question for this but let me ask anyway.      Is there a way I can use the above mentioned time and date format to sort the contents in the file. Or do I have to convert to epoch time and then sort it?

Comment: You would have to convert to a sortable value. `epoch` or `iso`

Answer (score 1):

```
while read -r host
do
    for qmgr in $(ssh musr@$host dspmq)
    do
        ssh musr@$host <cert command> <path to cert> |
        sed -n "s/ *..:[^,]*$//;/Valid/s/.*\, */$host\t:\t$qmgr\t:\t/p"
    done
done < "/home/MO/server.txt" > out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `sed` you could probably do something similar in `perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

local $/;
my ( $to ) = <DATA> =~ m/To: (.*)$/gm;
#print $to;
# print localtime->strftime("%A, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S %p");
my $timestamp = Time::Piece -> strptime($to, "%A, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S %p");
print $timestamp -> epoch, " => ", $timestamp -> strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

__DATA__
line 1
line 2
line 3
Valid From: Tuesday, 29 September 2015 10:40:13 AM To: Friday, 28 September 2018 10:40:13 AM
line 5
```

Which as a one liner would be:

```
perl -0777 -e 'print Time::Piece -> strptime(<>=~m/To: (.*)$/gm, "%A, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S %p") -> strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");'
```

Which should extract the desired date and convert it to a sortable format. (or you could use `epoch` of course.